# How to share wallpaper with text (i need to share play store link)

Tags: android, api, text, wallpaper

in my wallpaper app, i shared image to social media its working perfectly but i want to share image with text (play store link), how can i share image and text ?

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_share).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
                    shareWallpaper(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload);
                } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
                    shareWallpaper(wallpaper.image_url);
                }
            });
```

If you know this detail page let me know how to share image only text.This is the detail page I can use.I have tried many times and I have the answer

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Tools.getTheme(this);
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
    adsPref = new AdsPref(this);
    if (adsPref.getAdStatus().equals(AD_STATUS_ON) && adsPref.getAdType().equals(FAN)) {
        AudienceNetworkInitializeHelper.initialize(this);
    }
    if (adsPref.getBannerAdStatusDetail() != 0) {
        Tools.transparentStatusBar(this);
        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            Tools.darkNavigation(this);
        }
    } else {
        Tools.transparentStatusBarNavigation(this);
    }
    if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper_detail_rtl);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper_detail);
    }

    Tools.getRtlDirection(this);
    parent_view = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    position = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constant.POSITION, 0);
    wallpaper = (Wallpaper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(Constant.BUNDLE);
    items = (List<Wallpaper>) bundle.getSerializable(Constant.ARRAY_LIST);

    setupToolbar();
    loadView(position);
    setupViewPager();
    loadBannerAdNetwork();
    loadInterstitialAdNetwork();

}



    findViewById(R.id.btn_info).setOnClickListener(view -> showBottomSheetDialog(wallpaper));

    findViewById(R.id.btn_save).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
            downloadWallpaper(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload);
        } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
            downloadWallpaper(wallpaper.image_url);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btn_share).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
            shareWallpaper(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload);
        } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
            shareWallpaper(wallpaper.image_url);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btn_set_wallpaper).setOnClickListener(view -> {

        if (!verifyPermissions()) {
            return;
        }

        if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".gif") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".gif")) {
            if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
                setGif(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload);
            } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
                setGif(wallpaper.image_url);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
                    dialogOptionSetWallpaper(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload, wallpaper);
                } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
                    dialogOptionSetWallpaper(wallpaper.image_url, wallpaper);
                }
            } else {
                if (wallpaper.type.equals("upload")) {
                    setWallpaper(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload);
                } else if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
                    setWallpaper(wallpaper.image_url);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    favToggle(wallpaper);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (dbHelper.isFavoritesExist(wallpaper.image_id)) {
            dbHelper.deleteFavorites(wallpaper);
            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_favorite_removed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            dbHelper.addOneFavorite(wallpaper);
            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_favorite_added), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        favToggle(wallpaper);
    });

    updateView(wallpaper.image_id);

}

private void favToggle(Wallpaper wallpaper) {
    ImageView img_favorite = findViewById(R.id.img_favorite);
    if (dbHelper.isFavoritesExist(wallpaper.image_id)) {
        img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_fav);
    } else {
        img_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_fav_outline);
    }
}

public void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void showBottomSheetDialog(Wallpaper wallpaper) {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.include_info, null);
    FrameLayout lyt_bottom_sheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

    if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
        lyt_bottom_sheet.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bg_rounded_dark));
    } else {
        lyt_bottom_sheet.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bg_rounded_default));
    }

    if (wallpaper.image_name.equals("")) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_wallpaper_name)).setText("-");
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_wallpaper_name)).setText(wallpaper.image_name);
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_category_name)).setText(wallpaper.category_name);

    if (wallpaper.resolution.equals("0")) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_resolution)).setText("-");
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_resolution)).setText(wallpaper.resolution);
    }

    if (wallpaper.size.equals("0")) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_size)).setText("-");
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_size)).setText(wallpaper.size);
    }

    if (wallpaper.mime.equals("")) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mime_type)).setText("image/jpeg");
    } else {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_mime_type)).setText(wallpaper.mime);
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_count)).setText(Tools.withSuffix(wallpaper.views) + "");
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_download_count)).setText(Tools.withSuffix(wallpaper.downloads) + "");

    LinearLayout lyt_tags = view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_tags);
    if (wallpaper.tags.equals("")) {
        lyt_tags.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        lyt_tags.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") ArrayList<String> arrayListTags = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(wallpaper.tags.split(",")));
    AdapterTags adapterTags = new AdapterTags(this, arrayListTags);
    RecyclerView recycler_view_tags = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_tags);
    ChipsLayoutManager spanLayoutManager = ChipsLayoutManager.newBuilder(getApplicationContext()).setOrientation(ChipsLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL).build();
    recycler_view_tags.addItemDecoration(new SpacingItemDecoration(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.chips_space), getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.chips_space)));
    recycler_view_tags.setLayoutManager(spanLayoutManager);
    recycler_view_tags.setAdapter(adapterTags);

    if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
        mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.SheetDialogDark);
    } else {
        mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.SheetDialogLight);
    }
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }

    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = mBottomSheetDialog.getBehavior();
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });

    mBottomSheetDialog.show();
    mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
        mBottomSheetDialog = null;
        //Tools.lightNavigation(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this);
    });
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter() {
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_wallpaper_slider, container, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;
        Wallpaper wallpaper = items.get(position);

        final PhotoView imageView = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if (Config.ENABLE_CENTER_CROP_IN_DETAIL_WALLPAPER) {
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }

        imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (flag) {
                fullScreenMode(true);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                fullScreenMode(false);
                flag = true;
            }
        });

        final ProgressBar progressBar = imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        if (wallpaper.type.equals("url")) {
            Glide.with(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this)
                    .load(wallpaper.image_url.replace(" ", "%20"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_transparent)
                    .thumbnail(0.3f)
                    //.centerCrop()
                    .addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            Glide.with(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this)
                    .load(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wallpaper.image_upload.replace(" ", "%20"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_transparent)
                    .thumbnail(0.3f)
                    //.centerCrop()
                    .addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView);
        }

        container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;

    }


}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void dialogOptionSetWallpaper(String imageURL, Wallpaper wp) {
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dialog_set_wallpaper);
    single_choice_selected = items[0];
    int itemSelected = 0;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_set_title)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, itemSelected, (dialogInterface, i) -> single_choice_selected = items[i])
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_option_ok, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_applying), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
                        .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resource).getBitmap();
                                if (single_choice_selected.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.set_home_screen))) {
                                    try {
                                        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this);
                                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
                                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                                            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_applied), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            showInterstitialAdNetwork();
                                        }, Constant.DELAY_SET);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_failed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else if (single_choice_selected.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.set_lock_screen))) {
                                    try {
                                        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this);
                                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                                            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_applied), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            showInterstitialAdNetwork();
                                        }, Constant.DELAY_SET);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_failed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else if (single_choice_selected.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.set_both))) {
                                    try {
                                        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this);
                                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                                            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_applied), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            showInterstitialAdNetwork();
                                        }, Constant.DELAY_SET);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_failed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else if (single_choice_selected.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.set_crop))) {
                                    if (wp.type.equals("upload")) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityCropWallpaper.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("image_url", BASE_IMAGE_URL + wp.image_upload);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    } else if (wp.type.equals("url")) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityCropWallpaper.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("image_url", wp.image_url);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                } else if (single_choice_selected.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.set_with))) {
                                    //(new SetWallpaperFromOtherApp(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this)).execute(imageURL);
                                    if (wp.type.equals("upload")) {
                                        setWallpaperFromOtherApp(BASE_IMAGE_URL + wp.image_upload);
                                    } else if (wp.type.equals("url")) {
                                        setWallpaperFromOtherApp(wp.image_url);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                                Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_failed), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_option_cancel, null)
            .show();
}


                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                    Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}

public Boolean verifyPermissions() {
    int permissionExternalMemory = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionExternalMemory != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] STORAGE_PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, STORAGE_PERMISSIONS, 1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setWallpaperFromOtherApp(String imageURL) {

    if (!verifyPermissions()) {
        return;
    }

    Glide.with(this)
            .download(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
            .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    try {
                        if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".gif") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".gif")) {
                            Tools.setWallpaperFromOtherApp(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/gif");
                        } else if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".png") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".png")) {
                            Tools.setWallpaperFromOtherApp(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/png");
                        } else {
                            Tools.setWallpaperFromOtherApp(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/jpg");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }).submit();
}

public void setGif(String imageURL) {
    if (!verifyPermissions()) {
        return;
    }
    Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_preparing), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Glide.with(this)
            .download(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
            .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    try {
                        if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".gif") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".gif")) {
                            Tools.setGifWallpaper(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/gif");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }).submit();
}

public void downloadWallpaper(String imageURL) {
    if (!verifyPermissions()) {
        return;
    }
    Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_saving), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Glide.with(this)
            .download(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
            .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    try {
                        if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".gif") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".gif")) {
                            Tools.saveImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/gif");
                        } else if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".png") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".png")) {
                            Tools.saveImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/png");
                        } else {
                            Tools.saveImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/jpg");
                        }

                        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                            Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_saved), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateDownload(wallpaper.image_id);
                            showInterstitialAdNetwork();
                        }, Constant.DELAY_SET);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }).submit();
}

public void shareWallpaper(String imageURL) {
    if (!verifyPermissions()) {
        return;
    }
    Snackbar.make(parent_view, getString(R.string.snack_bar_preparing
    ), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Glide.with(this)
            .download(imageURL.replace(" ", "%20"))
            .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    try {
                        if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".gif") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".gif")) {
                            Tools.shareImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/gif");
                        } else if (wallpaper.image_upload.endsWith(".png") || wallpaper.image_url.endsWith(".png")) {
                            Tools.shareImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/png");
                        } else {
                            Tools.shareImage(ActivityWallpaperDetail.this, Tools.getBytesFromFile(resource), Tools.createName(imageURL), "image/jpg");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }).submit();
}



}
```

}

Comment: Image is a kind of document/file, but text(your link) is not. So, you can create a text/html file containing the link, then send the file along with your image file to share intent.

Comment: @Ananta Raha ok bro .. help with some example coding ?

Comment: You can create the URIs for the files and use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` to add them to your share intent. details: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-multiple-content

Comment: @Ananta Raha If I work, I get an error. Can you give me the text along with the picture?   exmple imge+text

Comment: @Ananta Rahamy detail page bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227290/how-do-i-share-text-along-with-the-image